# Deleting all fields from feature class with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, fields-attributes, delete, field-mapping

How do I delete all of the fields from a feature class in a simple way?

I don't want to loop over the fields using the Delete Field tool because this method is very slow in ArcPy.

I am using a polygon feature class, and I tried `arcpy.MultipartToSinglepart_management` but the feature class result saved all the fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could do this with MakeFeatureLayer on your original feature class, using field_info to "hide" all the fields, followed by CopyFeatures to get the features with no fields in a new feature class.

I investigated to make sure that this would work - and it did.  Here are some Python snippets of doing the steps manually to get the syntax right.

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/avhome/arcGISdata/Exploration.gdb/Samples","Samples_Layer","#","#","OBJECTID OBJECTID HIDDEN NONE;SHAPE SHAPE HIDDEN NONE;Dip_Angle Dip_Angle HIDDEN NONE;Strike Strike HIDDEN NONE;Rock Rock HIDDEN NONE;Description Description HIDDEN NONE")

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Samples_Layer","C:/avhome/arcGISdata/Exploration.gdb/SamplesNoAtts","#","0","0","0")
```

The only attributes on output are OBJECTID and SHAPE.

I wish that the ArcInfo Workstation command PULLITEMS had translated into an ArcGIS Desktop tool perhaps named Pull Fields or Filter Fields.

Answer (score 3):

You could work around it by creating a new feature class using the geometries of the old one but without the fields. The ArcGIS Resource Center has a section on working with [geometry in Python](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001s000000). There' a section on [reading](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Reading_geometries/002z0000001t000000/) and [writing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Reading_geometries/002z0000001t000000/) geometries that should cover what you need.