# Filtering attributes of selected features to new feature class using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, filter, select-by-location

I have a `gdb` of point features. I want to iterate through the gdb, select the point features that are within a polygon shapefile, and export the selected feature results to a new gdb. However, I only want to retain `geometry` and `uniqueid` fields for the new selected features that I want to output to my new gdb.

```
 # Import system modules
 import arcpy
 import os

 # Set environment settings
 arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data/input.gdb"

 # Set local variables
 out_workspace = "c:/output/output.gdb"

 # Boundary polygons for select by location
 boundaries = "C:/data/boundaries.shp"

 # Use ListFeatureClasses to generate a list of shapefiles in the workspace 
 fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

 # Execute CopyFeatures for each input shapefile
 for feature in fc_list:
     out_featureclass = os.path.join(out_workspace, feature + "_withinbounds")
     ### HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO FILTER ATTRIBUTES
     within_features = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(feature, "WITHIN", boundaries, "", "NEW_SELECTION")

     arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(within_features, out_featureclass)
```

Where would I put this code and how would I filter and retain just those attributes before exporting the new features using `CopyFeatures_management`?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap when trying to do this?  Have you considered using Delete Field?  Have you considered using a field mapping?

Comment: I am doing this strictly in a standalone Python script (I think I am using the arcpy version from ArcGIS Pro in my env, but running the code in Spyder IDE). So, how would I use delete fields or field mapping prior to exporting my selected output feature?

Comment: There's an answer at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/34478/115 which does it with ArcMap.  The code should be the same with ArcGIS Pro but I just found a better option which I'll put into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I think you should use the [Delete Field](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/delete-field.htm) tool in your script:

> You can specify either the fields to delete or the fields to keep.
>
> ...
>
> - To keep fields, use the **Field(s)** parameter to specify the fields to keep, and set the **Method** parameter to the **Keep
>   Fields** option.

I think you should use it after Copy Features so that you do not change the data that you are copying from.